# Method 'executeScript' not working - InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

in my app, i'm trying to execute some scripts using the executeScript method of InAppBrowser. Remembering that i'm using Ionic Framework v2, this is my code:

```
browser.executeScript({
            code: `
              $(".rodape.geral table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1)").css("min-width","auto");
              $(".rodape.geral table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1)").css("width","auto");
              $(".rodape.geral table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) table:nth-child(1)").attr("align","center");
            `
          }).then((e)=>{ console.log('JS adicionado.'); }).catch((e)=>{ console.log('Erro ao adicionar JS. '+e); });
```

Why the code is not working and not returning a callback? Thks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this code is in the `loadstop` event listener for the inAppBrowser.

The browser view needs to be loaded before you can run the JS.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you need to add this in `loadstop` event to add scripts or styles after the webpage loads.

```
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
  browser.executeScript({
    code : 'your javascript code'
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("in executeScript then()");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `executeScript` is a promise itself, so to make your code working you must write something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on(’$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop’, function (e, event) {
        browser.executeScript({
            code: `
              $(".rodape.geral table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1)").css("min-width","auto");
              $(".rodape.geral table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1)").css("width","auto");
              $(".rodape.geral table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) table:nth-child(1)").attr("align","center");
            `
          }).then((e)=>{ console.log('JS adicionado.'); }).catch((e)=>{ console.log('Erro ao adicionar JS. '+e); });
});
```

Comment: For me works fine but if, for example I want to get an element via getelementbyid if the element is not present, the callback not fires and neither catch callback block, some idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was having problem trying to send a simple console.log(). As many people may not use RxJS, I will share my final solution that works with javascript only:

```
var inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://<website>', '_blank', 'location=yes');


inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
   
    inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({
        code: `console.log('simple test')`
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("finish");
    });
});
```